# On an iPhone, how can I tell when an accurate GPS position has been acquired?

Tags: iphone

When taking photos I like having my pictures geo-tagged.

How can I tell when an accurate GPS location is available?

Answer (score 8):

Launch the Maps app and wait for the blue orb to pulse which indicates a full GPS lock. No other way to do this from within the Camera app.

Comment: Yep. The Camera app needs a little lock icon.